# C++: why can't i make a queue of a struct?

Tags: c++, struct, queue

I have the following code:

```
        #include <queue>
        struct Job                  
        {
        };
        queue<Job> _jobQueue;
```

But I get the error:

```
error: ISO C++ forbids declaration of âqueueâ with no type
```

How can I make a queue for my struct?

Comment: Sounds like you're missing an include?

Comment: (Note that names beginning with a leading underscore followed by a capital letter are reserved for the implementation -- the leading underscore is generally avoided for this reason.

Comment: Also, all names with global scope that start with an underscore are reserved - such as `_jobQueue` in this fragment.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the following

```
std::queue<Job> _jobQueue;
```

Answer (score 6):

You didn't `#include <queue>`.

EDIT: After your edit, you need to qualify that as `std::queue<Job>`.

Comment: forgot to put that in the example, but not the issue here :(

Comment: @Garrett: Yes, it is. Check your includes; check that you're qualifying in the `std` namespace as required.